# Ломается меню при ctrl+f5

Tags: html, jquery

**Ломается меню при нажатии `ctrl+f5`** (игнорировании кеширования) ломается меню, начинает красить по несколько sub элементов.
**С чем это может быть связано, как можно пофиксить?**

```js
   
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#menu> li.sub> a').click(function () {
            $('#menu li ul').slideUp();
            if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
                $(this).next().slideUp();
            } else {
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
            }
            $('#menu li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
        $('.sub ul li a').click(function () {
            var subIndex = $('.sub ul li a').index(this);
            $('.sub ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
        $('#menu> li').click(function () {
            //   $('.sub ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#menu> li.unSub> a').click(function () {
            $('#menu li ul').slideUp();
            if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
                $(this).next().slideUp();
            } else {
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
            }
            $('#menu li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
        $('.sub ul li a').click(function () {
            var subIndex = $('.unSub ul li a').index(this);
            $('.unSub ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
        $('#menu> li').click(function () {
            //   $('.sub ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

```css
#menu {
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #147ec3;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li {
    background: #147ec3;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#menu li a {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    padding:10px 15px;
    background: #147ec3;

    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu li.active {
    background: rgb(25, 83, 148);
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu li a:hover{
    background: rgb(25, 83, 148);
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu li a.active {
    background: rgb(25, 83, 148);
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0
}

#menu li ul li a {
    padding:8px 15px;
    background: #1ba2fb;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu li ul li a:after {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1em
}
#menu li ul li a:hover,
#menu li ul li a.active {
    background: #ff862e;
    color:white;
    padding-left:20px
}

#menu li.sub > a:before {
    content:'';
    height:6px;
    width:6px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-right-width:0;
    border-top-width:0;
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:14px
}
#menu li.unSub > a:before {
    content:'';
    height:6px;
    width:6px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:14px
}
#menu li.unSub > li:hover:before,
#menu li.unSub > li.active:before{

}

#menu li.sub > li:hover:before,
#menu li.sub > li.active:before{
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-right-width:0;
    border-top-width:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
        <li id="changeLog" class="unSub" ><a>Лог изменений</a>
        </li>
        <li class="unSub" style="border:none;" id="information"
           ><a> Общая
            информация по API</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class=" sub"><a>Данные</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="data" ><a>Нормализованные данные</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=" sub"><a>Задания</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="taskSchedulesMiniList" ><a>Список заданий</a>
                </li>
                <li id="taskSchedulesEdit" ><a>Редактирование</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=" sub"><a> Задачи</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="connect" ><a>Подключение модема к
                    серверу</a></li>
                <li id="disconnect" ><a>Отключение модема от
                    сервера</a></li>
                <li id="activateDevice" ><a>Активация прибора
                    учета</a></li>
                <li id="activateTV" ><a>Активация точки
                    учета</a></li>
                <li id="readData" ><a>Чтение данных с точки</a>
                </li>
                <li id="readDeviceProperties" ><a>Чтение
                    параметров
                    прибора</a></li>
                <li id="readTVProperties" ><a>Чтение параметров
                    точки</a>
                </li>
                <li id="writeDeviceProperties" ><a>Запись
                    параметров
                    прибора</a></li>
                <li id="writeTVProperties" ><a>Запись
                    параметров точки</a>
                </li>
                <li id="synchronizeTime" ><a>Синхронизация
                    времени</a></li>
                <li id="exchange" ><a>Обмен сообщениями</a>
                </li>
                <li id="tasksMiniList" ><a>Список задач для
                    объекта</a></li>
                <li id="rereadData" ><a>Перечитывание
                    данных</a></li>
                <li id="tasksGet" ><a>Получение</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class=" sub"><a> Пользовательские теги</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="change"><a>Создание и удаление тегов</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=" sub"><a> Поиск записей</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="tags" ><a>Доступные теги</a></li>
                <li id="organizationsSearch" ><a>Поиск
                    организаций</a></li>
                <li id="typeObjects" ><a>Поиск типов
                    объектов</a></li>
                <li id="modeObjects" ><a>Поиск режимов работы
                    объекта</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=" sub"><a> Настройка столбцов</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="edit" ><a>Редактирование</a></li>
                <li id="reset" ><a>Сброс</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub "><a> Настройка фильтров</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="filters" ><a>Доступные фильтры</a></li>
                <li id="add" ><a>Создание фильтра</a></li>
                <li id="filtersEdit" ><a>Редактирование
                    фильтра</a></li>
                <li id="deleteFilter" ><a>Удаление фильтра</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="sub"><a> Настройки системы</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="settings" ><a>Отображение элементов</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub"><a> Главные страницы</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="dashboards" ><a>Список страниц</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        </li>
        <li class="sub"><a> SIM карты </a>
            <ul>
                <li id="number" ><a>Получение номера
                    телефона</a></li>
                <li id="iccid" ><a>Получение номера ICCID </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="unSub" id="messages" ><a>Структура
            сообщений</a></li>
        <li class="unSub" id="status" ><a> Status-коды
            сущностей</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: Нет, консоль чистая.

Comment: @IsinMin я понимаю, что скорее всего мое предложение не поможет, но  можно попробовать заменить jQuery на последнюю версию

Comment: Почти всё меню можно реализовать с помощью css. Зачем jquery использовать?

Comment: Не заметил описанного поведения ни в Firefox, ни в Chrome, и да, зачем тут jQuery столько? 90% поведения данного меня можно на css реализовать